# Raising an event on a new thread in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, events, delegates

**I need to raise an event from a form on a new thread.**

*(I don't believe the reason for this is relevant, but just in case:  I'll be raising events from code within a form's WndProc sub.  If the code handling the event blocks with something on a form [such as a msgbox], then all sorts of trouble occurs with disconnected contexts and what not.  I've confirmed that raising events on new threads fixing the problem.)*

**This is what I am currently doing:**

```
Public Event MyEvent()

Public Sub RaiseMyEvent()
    RaiseEvent MyEvent
End Sub

Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As System.Windows.Forms.Message)
    Dim t As New Threading.Thread(AddressOf RaiseMyEvent)
    t.Start()
End Sub
```

**Is there a better way?**

It is my understanding that events in VB are actually made up of delegates in the background.  Is there any way to raise events in new threads without creating subs for each?  Or, is there a more appropriate method I should be using?

Comment: Why do you need to raise an event on a new thread?

Comment: @Matt, Read my post, first paragraph in italics.  I need to raise events within WndProc.  If the code handling those events needs WndProc messages to work, a crash happens, because WndProc is blocked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can eliminate the RaiseMyEvent sub like this:

```
Public Class Class1

    Public Event MyEvent()

    Sub Demo()
        Dim t As New Threading.Thread(Sub() RaiseEvent MyEvent())
        t.Start()
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: This does not work if one uses a background worker.

Answer (score 5):

Don't know if this will help, but i'll always do threading and events like this:

```
Event MyEvent(ByVal Var1 As String, ByVal Var2 As String)

Private Delegate Sub del_MyEvent(ByVal Var1 As String, ByVal Var2 As String)

Private Sub StartNewThread()
    'MAIN UI THREAD

    Dim sVar1 As String = "Test"
    Dim sVar2 As String = "Second Var"

    Dim oThread As New Threading.Thread(New Threading.ParameterizedThreadStart(AddressOf StartNewThread_Threaded))
    With oThread
        .IsBackground = True
        .Priority = Threading.ThreadPriority.BelowNormal
        .Name = "StartNewThread_Threaded"

        .Start(New Object() {sVar1, sVar2})
    End With
End Sub
Private Sub StartNewThread_Threaded(ByVal o As Object)
    'CHILD THREAD
    Dim sVar1 As String = o(0)
    Dim sVar2 As String = o(1)

    'Do threaded operation
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)

    'Raise event
    RaiseEvent_MyEvent(sVar1, sVar2)

End Sub

Public Sub RaiseEvent_MyEvent(ByVal Var1 As String, ByVal Var2 As String)

    If Me.InvokeRequired Then
        'Makes the sub threadsafe (I.e. the event will only be raised in the UI Thread)
        Dim oDel As New del_MyEvent(AddressOf RaiseEvent_MyEvent)
        Me.Invoke(oDel, Var1, Var2)
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'MAIN UI THREAD
    RaiseEvent MyEvent(Var1, Var2)
End Sub
```